# Achieving SQL 3NF normalisation

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, normalization

I'm trying to achieve 3NF using the data I have but I'm getting confused. These are the tables I have:

```
FACULTY table    DEPARTMENT table        STUDSGROUP table         STUDENT table
FACULTY_ID       DEPARTMENT_ID           STUDSGROUP_ID            STUDENT_ID
FACULTY_NAME     DEPARTMENT_NAME         ACADEMIC YEAR            STUDENTS_NAME
FACULTY_DEAN     HEAD OF DEPARTMENT      COURSE/SPECIALITY        STUDENTS_GROUP
                                                                  COURSE/SPECIALITY 
                                                                  DOB/DATE OF BIRTH
```

I am thinking I can do it like this below, though I think I'm not right.

```
FACULTY table
FACULTY_ID,PK
DEAN

DEPARTMENT table
DEPARTMENT_ID,PK
FACULTY_ID,fk
DEPARTMENT_NAME
HEAD OF DEPARTMENT


STUDSGROUP table
STUDSGROUP_ID, pk
ACADEMIC YEAR
SPECIALITY

STUDENTS table
STUDENT_ID, pk
FACULTY_NAME,FK
STUDSGROUP_ID,FK
FIRST_NAME
LAST_NAME
DOB
```

Comment: It might help to know *why* you are trying to achieve 3NF (If this is homework, could you add the homework tag? People are willing to help but would prefer to know). Also, what is it about the design you have that you don't think is 3NF?

Comment: I added a homework tag i forgot to do that,im trying to learn on normalisation i thought of just doing this as an example to help me understand more

Comment: i just want to be sure if im doing it right am i?

Comment: You should probably hava a person table and use it for the "HEAD OF DEPARTMENT", but it probably adds a lot of useless joins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normalization requires that you know how the various parts of the schema are related.  Up to 3NF and BCNF (almost, but not quite the same thing — though you'd be hard-pushed to find a practical example of 3NF that is not also in BCNF), the most important feature is the functional dependency.

Another key point is 'conservation'; you shouldn't lose columns altogether.  For example, your original Faculty table has an ID number, a name and a dean.  Your revised version is missing the faculty name; that is a bug in your redesign.

You've identified that each department belongs to a faculty, which seems plausible enough.

Your revised Student Groups table seems to be the same as in the original.  That's probably OK, though maybe the course/speciality part of that means that a student group is associated with a department, and hence a faculty.  If so, then the you might need a courses/specialities table that identifies the course/speciality and the department, leaving the student group to identify a particular year group within the course/speciality.

Your original students table has a course/speciality and also a student group; this leaves open the possibility that the data will say Student X is doing Archaeology in the Students table, but the Student Group indicates that Student X is doing Music.  Is that allowed?  If not, would you be best served by just having the Student Group in the Students table, leaving that to identify course/speciality, and year, and department, and hence faculty?  Your revised schema adds a faculty ID to the students table (but does remove the course/speciality); that still leaves opportunities for conflict within the data.

Do you need a table to identify valid academic years?  Possibly not.  Should there be a table for staff, so that you can identify deans and department heads.  Can the dean of a faculty be a department head?  Of departments outside their faculty?